# Finding the mean of two columns with two different classes/labels

Tags: r, tidyverse

right now I'm trying to create a data frame that contains the mean of two columns for two separate labels/categories.

But, I don't know how to calculate the mean for two columns, it just returns the same mean for both winner and opponent/loser.

Currently, I'm using the tidyverse library.

Here is the original data frame:

```
winner_hand winner_ht   winner_ioc  winner_age  opponent_hand   opponent_ht opponent_ioc    opponent_age    result  name
<chr>   <dbl>   <chr>   <dbl>   <chr>   <dbl>   <chr>   <dbl>   <fct>   <chr>
R   178 JPN 29.00479    R   NA  RUS 22.88569    winner  Kei Nishikori
R   NA  RUS 22.88569    R   188 FRA 33.70568    winner  Daniil Medvedev
R   178 JPN 29.00479    R   188 FRA 31.88227    winner  Kei Nishikori
R   188 FRA 33.70568    R   NA  AUS 19.86858    winner  Jo Wilfried Tsonga
R   NA  RUS 22.88569    R   196 CAN 28.01095    winner  Daniil Medvedev
R   188 FRA 31.88227    R   NA  JPN 26.40383    winner  Jeremy Chardy
```

My code:

```
age_summary <- game_data %>%
                group_by(result) %>%
                summarize(mean_age = mean(winner_age))
age_summary
```

Resulting Data frame:

```
result  mean_age
<fct>   <dbl>
winner  27.68495
loser   27.68495
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want summaries from two columns, you need expressions for each column in the call to `summarize()`.

Example with fake data, since your excerpt only has one value for the 'result' column:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- read_csv(
"result, winner_age, opponent_age
A, 5, 10
A, 6, 11,
B, 12, 2
B, 13, 1")

dat %>%
  group_by(result) %>%
  # note: two expressions here:
  summarise(mean_winner_age = mean(winner_age),
            mean_opponent_age = mean(opponent_age))
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  result mean_winner_age mean_opponent_age
  <chr>            <dbl>             <dbl>
1 A                  5.5              10.5
2 B                 12.5               1.5
```